# Python Debugger (PDB): open currently active python file in editor

Tags: python, pdb

Is there some way to get during debugging with `pdb`:

- currently opened python file
- currently active line of code
- indent on the current line of code

and open the file in default text editor?

Example. After running the code below and then using `s` to step into `Path` execution and using some command/code I'm looking for I wanted to open file `c:\python311\lib\pathlib.py` at line 868 and at 5th symbol.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
p = Path()
```

The problem is only about getting current python file in `pdb` context. Opening file itself is trivial `os.system(r"C:\test.py")`. Active line code and indent is needed so I'd be able to open it in VS Code at exact position: `vsc --goto "C:\test.py:1:5"` (comes from `vsc --goto "<filepath>:<linenumber>:<x-coordinates>"`).

It would be nice if it was some native way to do it directly from `pdb` but since there's nothing related in the documentation, the solution is probably to make some custom method - which is okay too.

I've already tried to use `inspect` module but it seems that `pdb` is starting new frame where actual debugged python file is not accessible:

```py
from inspect import currentframe, getframeinfo
frameinfo = getframeinfo(currentframe())
print(frameinfo.filename, frameinfo.lineno)
# <stdin> 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution. Investigating `pdb` module, I've found that `Pdb` class instance has `self.curframe` and `self.botframe` attributes allowing to access code frames and their paths. When we do `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` it automatically creates an instance of `Pdb` class, we need to access.

But I haven't found any other way to get the instance besides the hacky one - `pdb.set_trace()` is setting system trace (using `sys.settrace`) to `Pdb_instance.trace_dispatch`. Therefore we can retrieve `Pdb_instance.trace_dispatch` using `sys.gettrace()` and get `Pdb` instance with `__self__`.

Final solution is the `vscode()` method in the snippet below. To make it always accessible with pdb you can put it in your `pdb.py` file (typically it's in `Python311\Lib\pdb.py`). I guess, the good place for it would be after `def set_trace(*, header=None):`.

Then you'd be able to call `import pdb; pdb.vscode()` during pdb debugging and it will automatically open current file in VS Code. Voila!

You can also add `monkey_patch_vscode` to your pdb - it will patch one of the `Pdb` methods and you'd be able to open VS Code with just `vscode()`.

PS Need to make sure you have `vsc` (link to VS Code) is accessable from your system Path.

```py
def monkey_patch_vscode():
    def wrap():
        original_setup = Pdb.setup
        def wrapped_setup(self, *args):
            res = original_setup(self, *args)
            self.curframe.f_globals["vscode"] = vscode
            return res
        return wrapped_setup
    Pdb.setup = wrap()
monkey_patch_vscode()

def vscode():
    """open file currently debugged with pdb in VS code
    (at current line and indent)"""
    import os, linecache, sys, types
    def get_current_pdb_file():
        pdb = sys.gettrace().__self__
        # there is also .botframe - the frame when pdb entered
        frame = pdb.curframe # type: types.FrameType
        return frame.f_code.co_filename, frame.f_lineno
    filepath, line = get_current_pdb_file()
    current_line = linecache.getlines(filepath)[line]
    indent = len(current_line) - len(current_line.lstrip()) + 1
    def vscode_run(filepath, line, indent=1):
        # `line` and `indent` starting from 1
        os.system(f'vsc --goto "{filepath}:{line}:{indent}"')

    vscode_run(filepath, line, indent)
```